# Second text box to allow only smaller number

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have two text box.
User enters numbers in this box. I am looking for a solution such that the first box number needs to be greater than or equal to second box number and vice versa.

Say for example, if user enter 70 in first box, second box should accept only number 70 or less. Is there a way to achieve this. This is in an aspx page.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `focusout` with condition like below.

```js
$("#txt2")
  .focusout(function() {
    var num = $('#txt1').val();
    if ($('#txt2').val() > num)
      alert('false post'); //Your other code or message
    else
      alert('true post');
  })
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="number" id='txt1' />
<input type="number" id='txt2' />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get both the number and do a comparison

```js
function validateInput() {
  let getFirstVal = document.getElementById('firstInput').value;
  let getSecondVal = document.getElementById('secondInput').value;
  if (isNaN(getFirstVal)) {
    console.log('Enter only number');
    document.getElementById('secondInput').setAttribute('disabled', true)
  } else if (getFirstVal === '') {
    document.getElementById('secondInput').setAttribute('disabled', true)
  } else if (parseInt(getSecondVal, 10) > parseInt(getFirstVal, 10)) {
    document.getElementById('secondInput').value = '';
    console.log('Enter lower number');
  } else {
    document.getElementById('secondInput').removeAttribute('disabled')

  }

}
```

```html
<div>
  <input type='text' id='firstInput' onkeyup='validateInput()'>
  <input disabled type='text' id='secondInput' onkeyup='validateInput()'>
</div>
```